# How to run AppImage on the command line

Tags: command-line, files, appimage

I'm sometimes working on the command line (or in the Ranger file manager), and it's annoying to have to move to a graphical interface to double-click on a AppImage. It looks like Ranger tries `xdg-open`; I tried that on the command line, myself, and that fails. My permissions are correct, so how can I actually run an AppImage from the command line?

Comment: Perhaps by including the complete path like this: `/path/to/file.AppImage` (without the initial dot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making it executable `chmod +x` file and running it with `./file` worked for me.

Comment: Example of a run instruction is: `$ ./Tulip-5.7.1.AppImage` to make it more pedagogic